# how to capture error from python's subprocess.run, while using timeout

Tags: subprocess, timeout, python-3.7

I cannot figure out how to use python's subprocess.run to capture stdout, stderr, and exitcode ... and whatever else can be captured.  I also have  to use the timeout option because some of the thousands of commands I'm running hang, ie., run interminably.  I bet I have missed something obvious, and I apologize.  I've spent days on this and cannot figure it out.

Any help you could give me would be much appreciated.

Here's my defective code:

```
seconds = timeout
try:
    proc = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, timeout=seconds)

except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('This process ran too long:\n' + cmd + '\n')
        
out, err = proc.communicate()
exitcode = proc.returncode

if len(out) == 0: out="''"
if len(err) == 0: err="''"
#
return exitcode, out, err
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of

`out, err = proc.communicate()`

use

`out, err = proc.stdout, proc.stderr`

Regarding your except clause, I'm not sure if you'll be able to get stdout, stderr and returncode after a timeout. Give it a check. If not, then consider `return "", "", 1` or something like that in your except clause.